# How can I print long long integer in xv6?

Tags: c, xv6

I found out that I can not use "%llu" or "%lld" in xv6.
All I could use is "%d" for printing integer.
Is there any way I can print long long integer in xv6?

I tried converting long long to string, but things didn't go well.

Comment: You have to convert to one of the known format specifiers, either `%d`, `%x`, `%p`, or `%s`. I'd pick a null-terminated string in this case. What have you tried to convert to a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can split up the number. With a 32-bit `int` this should work for values up to `4294967295999999999`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    unsigned long long n = 1234500000006789;
    //unsigned long long n = 4294967295999999999;
    unsigned int top = (unsigned int)(n / 1000000000);
    unsigned int bot = (unsigned int)(n % 1000000000);
    if(top)
        printf("%u%09u\n", top, bot);
    else
        printf("%u\n", bot);
}
```

Output

```
1234500000006789
```

For signed values, detect the sign first, output `-` and negate.